# How to display a timer using PyQt5 for Python

Tags: python, user-interface, timer

I'm making a game where I would like a timer to be displayed on the screen after the user clicks on 'NEW GAME', to keep track of how long they've been playing. I have a class that runs the timer fine by itself, but when I incorporate it into the rest of my game and then on top of that, try to display the updated values of the timer, no values in the UI are updated and the printout of the timer doesn't even occur in the terminal. I've tried running the timer in the same thread as the game-setup process and I've also tried creating a new thread to run the timer but neither work. The game loads up and functions fine, with the exception of the timer not counting upwards and not displaying the updated timer values. Where am I going wrong here?

Here is my standalone Timer class, which again, works fine by itself.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys

def startThread(functionName, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    if len(args) == 0:
        t = threading.Thread(target=functionName)
    else:
        try:
            t = threading.Thread(target=functionName, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        except:
            try:
                if args is None:
                    t = threading.Thread(target=functionName, kwargs=kwargs)
            except:
                t = threading.Thread(target=functionName)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

class Timer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Timer, self).__init__()

    def start_timer(self):
        print("Starting timer...")
        Timer.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        Timer.time = QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)
        Timer.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick)
        Timer.timer.start(1000)

    def tick(self):
        Timer.time = Timer.time.addSecs(1)
        self.update_UI('%s' % Timer.time.toString("hh:mm:ss"))

    def update_UI(self, text_string):
        print(text_string)
        # This is where the text would be sent to try and update the UI

Timer().start_timer()
```

This is more or less how my game-setup class is structured - currently I'm showing the version that uses threading:

```
class BuildUI(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_game):

    def __init__(self):
        super(BuildUI, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.easy_mode = 38
        self.user_available_cells = []
        self.start_easy_game.triggered.connect(lambda: self.setup_game(self.easy_mode))

    def setup_game(self, hidden_count):
        def create_game_board():
            startThread(Timer().start_timer)
            self.game = BuildGame()
                    #The BuildGame class is not deliberately not shown

        startThread(create_game_board)

class GAME(object):
    def __init__(self):
        GAME.app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        GAME.UI = BuildUI()
        GAME.UI.show()
        GAME.app.exec_()

def main():
    GAME()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: many GUIs can work only in main thread. Other threads can't access widget. You could use `print()` in different places to see which part is executed and want values you have in variables.

Comment: I don't know why you use thread if `QTimer` can work in `GUI` without thread.

Comment: @furas well obviously that's why I'm here asking.

Comment: simply use `print()` to test your code, or learn how to use debugger. But I would suggest to write it all without thread.

Comment: @furas I mentioned how I was not seeing any print statements with regards to the timer updating. Beyond that, there's not much else to print. Additionally, if the timer was printing the values but not displaying them, then that would be one thing, but the timer isn't even running, I have the sense the issue lies with where the app.exec_()`line is placed...but I'm about all out of my own ideas on what could be the issue.

Comment: you can put `print()` in different places to display message which inform which part of code is executed - this way you can see which part of code doesn't work correctly. maybe some part doesn't work as you expected and it doesn't even try to start thread. It is called "print debuging".

Comment: I would rather create widget with timer and use it in new window or run second window using only app - `GAME.app` - without second app - `app = QtCore.QCoreApplication`. Using thead has own problems like communication between threads and control other thread from main thread.

Comment: @furas Yeah I understand how to debug my code just fine. As I mentioned, printing will not help in this scenario. I am already running in debug mode, so I can pause the code wherever I want as it is and I know exactly the last line that is run in the Timer class. Additionally, as I also said, everything else runs fine.

Comment: I already tried removing the second app declaration in the Timer class and that had no effect.

Comment: I finally reduced your code so I could run it and it shows me warnings in console/terminal: `QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread` and `QApplication::exec: Must be called from the main thread`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to getting this to work is by using signals. Leaving the `Timer` class exactly as it is, the only modifications to be done are in the initialization of the `GAME` class, a signal needs to be added at the beginning of the BuildUI class and then using emit() to trigger that signal just before the `self.game = BuildGame()` call.

```
class BuildUI(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMainWindow, sudoku_ui.Ui_sudoku_game):
    # This signal just triggers a msgbox to display, telling the user the game is loading
    process_start = PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    # this is called to automatically close the msgbox window       
    process_finished = PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    # This signal, when called will start the timer
    start_game_timer = PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(BuildUI, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.easy_mode = 38
        self.user_available_cells = []
        self.start_easy_game.triggered.connect(lambda: self.setup_game(self.easy_mode))

    def setup_game(self, hidden_count):
        def create_game_board():
            self.game = BuildGame()
            # Now that the game is built, the timer can start
            # This is the emit which will start the timer
            GAME.UI.start_game_timer.emit()

        startThread(create_game_board)

class GAME(object):
    def __init__(self):
        GAME.app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        GAME.UI = BuildUI()
        GAME.dialog_box = MsgPrompt()

        # This is the key right here - initializing the timer class
        GAME.timer = Timer()
        # This line below attaches a function to the emit() call - which will kick off the timer
        GAME.UI.start_game_timer.connect(GAME.timer.start_timer)
        # The below referenced class is deliberately omitted from this post
        GAME.UI.process_start.connect(GAME.dialog_box.show_dialog_box)
        GAME.UI.process_finished.connect(GAME.dialog_box.hide_dialog_box)
        GAME.UI.show()
        GAME.app.exec_()

def main():
    GAME()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```